# shell grep command from the output of wget

Tags: grep, wget

I have a script to check the status of a url. I am trying to grep for the word `connected` from the below mentioned wget command output and print `Running` if it is found else print `Not Running`. How can I modify my grep to print only the word without the all the output from wget command

```
#!/bin/ksh
STAT=`wget 'http://server:port/ABC_Service/app' | grep connected`
if [ -z "$STAT" ] ; then
   echo "Running"
else
  echo "Not Running"
fi
```

**Output of `wget` command:**

```
--2013-05-31 11:09:32--  http://server:port/ABC_Service/app
Resolving server... 10.109.136.31
Connecting to server|10.109.136.31|:port... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
```

Desired Output from my script:

```
Running
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return code

```
#!/bin/ksh
#use your wget command in place of echo below
echo "connected" 2>&1 | grep connected >/dev/null
retcode=$?
if [ $retcode = 0 ]
then
   echo "Running"
else
  echo "Not Running"
fi
```

Comment: Its printing the output of whole wget command and also its printing retcode as `1` and showing as `Not Running` when its connected.                     `--2013-05-31 11:09:32--  http://server:port/ABC_Service/app
Resolving server... 10.109.136.31
Connecting to server|10.109.136.31|:port... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
Not Running`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Bash, then the variable $? reads the exit status of the last command executed.